# CodeIgniter - Call method inside a model?

Tags: codeigniter

I have the following code:

```
class Badge extends CI_Model
{
    public function foo()
    {
        echo $this->bar('world');
    }

    public function bar($word)
    {
        return $word;
    }
}
```

But it always gives me an error on the line where `echo $this->bar('world');` is.

> Call to undefined method (......)

Comment: The code above will work, assuming that you're loading your model properly and calling `foo()` properly. Are you sure that you are? Where are you loading the model and calling `foo()`? And is that your actual code above, or a simplified version? If it's not your actual code, please paste that instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your not loading your model inside your controller:

```
public function test()
{
    $this->load->model('badge');
    $this->badge->foo();
}
```

Because the code works - I've just tested it by pasting using your model unedited:

```
class Badge extends CI_Model
{
    public function foo()
    {
        echo $this->bar('world');
    }

    public function bar($word)
    {
        return $word;
    }
}
```

output:

```
world
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid any external call dependecy you need to get the Codeigniter instance and call the method through the instance.

```
class Badge extends CI_Model
{
    public function foo()
    {   
        $CI =& get_instance();

        echo $CI->Badge->bar('world');
    }

    public function bar($word)
    {
        return $word;
    }
}
```