# codeigniter method error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using the following from the controller to call a method from the model but receiving and error:

```
//from the controller:(main.php)

<?php
class Main extends CI_Controller {

   public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
   }

   function index() {
   .....
   $this->load->view('view_form');

   }//END Fn index()

   function get_th() {

   //$the=$this->input->post('th', TRUE);
   $d['shit']=$this->model_data->tst();
   $this->load->view('view_form',$d);

   }//END Fn get_th()

}//END Cls Main
?>

//from the model:(model_data.php)
<?php
class Model_data extends CI_Model {

   function slider() {
...
   }//END Fn slider()

   function check_input($data) {
...
   }//END Fn check_input()

   function tst() {
        $tsts= "hellos";
        return $this->tsts;
   }

}//END Cls model_data
?>
```

$autoload['model'] = array('model_data');

The error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Model_data::tst() in ... application\controllers\main.php...

Comment: Can you post the entire code for the model and controller?  I would first check for (1) loading model model_data and (2) spelling in the class definition.

Comment: that's the code:
[link]
http://pastebin.com/hqAzA5x1
[/link]

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot to load the model in the controller.

```
$this->load->model('Model_name');

function get_th() {

   $this->load->model('model_data');
   $d['shit']=$this->model_data->tst();
   $this->load->view('view_form',$d);

   }
```

Comment: autoloaded:
$autoload['model'] = array('model_data');

[link] http:www./pastebin.com/hqAzA5x1 [/link]

Comment: refer this same as your problems seems like model is not loaded in your code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523062/code-igniter-call-method-inside-a-model

Comment: did you look at the pastebin.com link?

Comment: function get_th() {

   $this->load->model('model_data');
   $d['shit']=$this->model_data->tst();
   $this->load->view('view_form',$d);

   }   add this code in your controller say what error it say and try call http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523062/code-igniter-call-method-inside-a-model   that simple mvc runs in your code

Answer (score 0):

FIXED :/ can t believe I had an additional bracket at the the end of a long file :( wtf

"}"<-- this was the problem.

btw as I said @pramodhkumar use autoload.php.. I had the model autoload so no need for $this->load->...